# getting the name of the element that is checked in checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table which is dynamically created. The number of rows and coloumns wil be different for each search depending on search results.. This is how im creating a table

```
for(count = 0 ; count < facetList.length ;){
    facetsString+="<div id='test'>";
    facetsString+="<table id='facetTable' border='1' width='830px' style='margin-left:30px; margin-top:30px; font-family:Tahoma; '>";
    for( var i=0 ; i< 6 && count < facetList.length ; i++  ){
        facetsString+="<tr>";
        for(var j=0;j<4 && count < facetList.length ; j++){

            facetsString+="<td><form><input type='checkbox'></form>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+facetList[count].term+  "(" + facetList[count].count + ")" + "</td>";

            count++;
        }
    facetsString+="</tr>";
    }
facetsString+="</table>";

facetsString+="</div>";
}

return facetsString;
};
```

Now there is checkbox before each entry in the table..I want to display the name of the element whose box is checked...

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('name'));
})`

Comment: Could you explain the wrking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that wrked.

```
function checkCount()
{


 var allVals = new Array();
    var newVals = new Array();

    $('#panel :input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() 
    {
        $("#slctFacet").empty();
         newVals.push($(this).parent().text());
         allVals.push($(this).val());

    });
    //alert(allVals);
   // alert(newVals);

    var fctArrayLength=newVals.length;
    //alert(fctArrayLength);
    if(fctArrayLength==0)
        {
        $("#slctFacet").empty();
        }
    else
        {
            for(var i=0;i<fctArrayLength;i++)
                {
            $("#slctFacet").append(newVals[i]);


                }
        }
}
$(":checkbox").click(checkCount);
};
```

Comment: You are not defining the value of Check box. Please tell if you want value of check box or its next element's value. By the way, there was a syntax error in my code. I resolved it now.

Comment: Please tell if you want functionality like this JSFiddle Link?

http://jsfiddle.net/nmkSm/2/

Comment: Man, don't use `new Array()`. `var allVals = []` is better for all the possible reasons. Also, don't use `alert`, we're in 2012, `console.log` is the way to go nowadays :)

Comment: Sorry sir, and thanx for drawing my attension to my old ways..
I have update the JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/nmkSm/4/

Comment: How does this console.log wrk?

Comment: Thanks for the jfiddle example...did some editing and it wrked... Thank you so mch...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the form from its name
var form = document.forms.formName,
// Prepare an array to get the values
    vals = []

// For each element in the form
[].forEach.call( form.elements, function ( el ) {

    // Check if it's a checkbox. If it is, check if it's checked
    if ( el.type === 'checkbox' && el.checked === true ) {

        // Add the value to the "vals" array
        vals.push( el.value )
    }
} )

// Now all the values are available in the "vals" array
console.log( vals )
```